# Unable to connect Lambda in private subnet to S3 through VPCE Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I've been trying to connect to S3 bucket from a lambda residing in a private subnet. I did the exact same thing for Ec2 instance and it worked like a charm, I'm not sure why with lambda it's such an issue. My lambda times out after a certain defined interval.

Here's my lambda's VPC configuration
[image]

Here's the security group output configuration:
[image]

Below are the outbound rules of the subnet associated with lambda
[image]

As you can see, I created a VPC endpoint to route my traffic through the VPC but it doesn't work. I'm not sure what am I missing here. Below is the VPC Endpoint configuration.

[image]

I've given full access to S3 in policy like this:

```
{
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Principal": "*"
    }
]
```

}

When I run my lambda code, I get timeout error as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can access **Amazon S3 objects** using VPC endpoint only when the S3 objects are in the **same Region** as the **Amazon S3 gateway VPC endpoint**. Confirm that your objects and endpoint are in the **same Region**.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your situation, I performed the following steps:

- Created an **AWS Lambda function** that calls `ListBuckets()`. Tested it *without* attaching to a VPC. It worked fine.
- Created a **VPC** with just a **private subnet**
- Added an **Amazon S3 Endpoint Gateway** to the VPC and subnet
- Reconfigured the Lambda function to use the VPC and subnet
- Tested the Lambda function -- it worked fine

I suspect your problem might lie with the Security Group attached to the Lambda function. I left my Outbound rules as "All Traffic 0.0.0.0/0" rather than restricting it. Give that a try and see if it makes things better.

Comment: Hi @John. ListBuckets() works for me as well. However, list_objects_v2() or list_objects() fxn give me timeout error. I'm not sure why that's the case but if this was a policy issue, it would've thrown 403. Here's the code: https://ibb.co/nB8VN40

Comment: If you can list buckets but not list objects, then that's very weird. It means you've connected fine. I don't know what would be causing the timeout. Does the bucket have lots of objects? If so, try increasing your Lambda timeout some more. BTW, the code isn't using the `Prefix` you defined.

Comment: I removed the prefix to see if it can list the objects directly which are available immediately inside the bucket. There are not a lot of objects in the bucket. I increased the timeout to 30sec but it still same issues... thanks for helping out anyways